# Angular 1.4 - How to move logic for ng-click item from template to controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click

I am looking to modify some code to add more functionality to an ng-click event that is within an ng-repeat.

The current code updates the selected property for the item in the list:

```
<li ng-repeat="value in facet.values" ng-click="value.selected = (value.selected == 0) ? 1 : 0; accountSearch()">
  ...
</li>
```

I'd like to update the selected property but also fire an event to our analytics provider:

```
<li ng-repeat="value in facet.values" ng-click="itemClicked(value)">
  ...
</li>
```

Then in my controller:

```
$scope.itemClicked = function(value){
  value.selected = (value.selected == 0) ? 1 : 0; $scope.accountSearch();
  // do other things
}
```

The issue is that the above code will not actually modify the selected property in the template. How can I recreate this behavior but move the logic to the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Value is not returned to the template, so it's lost. Try the following:

```
<li ng-repeat="value in facet.values" ng-click="itemClicked($index)">
  ...
</li>


$scope.itemClicked = function(index){
  $scope.facet.values[index].selected = ($scope.facet.values[index].selected == 0) ? 1 : 0; 
  $scope.accountSearch();
}
```

Comment: okay thank you. This is somewhat complicated because my ng-repeat is inside another ng-repeat: `<div ng-repeat="facet in data.facets | orderObjectBy: 'order'">`

Comment: Retrieve the first index too and pass it as the second argument and then do $scope.facets[index1].values[index2].selected=...

Answer (score 3):

The reason why it's not updating is that it's probably not bound to the model anymore. Try this:

```
<li ng-repeat="value in facet.values" ng-click="itemClicked(value)">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="value.selected" />
</li>
```

You may want to use `ng-checked` instead of `ng-model` based on your use case